# Magento upgrade 1.9.3 to 2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.3, migration, magento-upgrade

I need to upgrade magento 1.9.3 to 2.3. I have read the migration process at magento docs and other sites.

Now I have a few `questions- 1.`

`Magento 2.3` requires `php 7` while our `magento 1.9` does not support php 7. I have found a patch but I am not confident about this as I do not want to distrub the running site. Should I try this patch?

`2.`

We can move to a new server also if that makes things easier. Should I try to install this in a new folder at the present server and later redirect it to the new installation or install at new server and change the dns?

What will you suggest? I am in a position to do both of them.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions `magento 1` database setup the other sever so your magento 1 site is not distrub and after upgrade the side

First the you backup the your `magento 1` database and setup the your new server.And check 
the `php version 7.2 to 7.3`.

Second the your `magento 1` import database.And install the fresh `magento 2`.

After setup refer this link :-

**https://www.matridtech.net/a-simple-step-by-step-guide-for-migrating-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/**

And any query let me know

Comment: SO I need to install this patch https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-1-official-php-7-2-patches/ before installing magento 2.3 in a new folder?

Comment: what your question please explain in briefly??